# How best to handle flags on posts that are subsequently edited, making the flag obsolete or wrong?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I correctly flag a question for being unclear. The question is then edited to provide missing details, so that it is clear and on-topic. My flag now appears to be wrong, so would get declined.

What is the proper thing to do in this case? Both for me as the flag raiser as well as those judging the flag as helpful or not? The ideal thing would be for me to retract the flag, but I don't get a notification when the question is edited - especially if the flag is judged before I have a chance to retract it. Do the close-vote reviewers see that the flag was raised on an earlier un-edited version of the question?

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed on the main meta site [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105453/236563).

In essence, no, reviewers don't see the original version of the post, they see it as it stands at the point of review.

However, reviewers have the ability, should they so wish, to look at the edit history.  That enables them to see earlier versions of the post.  On the sites where I review, I do this if I suspect that the flag came before an edit.  Also, where I moderate I would mark the flag as helpful.

If you do notice that an edit renders your flag obsolete, it would be helpful to retract it.  However, as you say, it isn't easy to spot.  I wouldn't worry too much about the occasional flag that slips through the net.